# Trying to make urls of the form <base_url>/boards/<name> in ruby on rails and getting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am using ruby on rails to make a simple social networking site that includes different message boards for each committee of a student group. I want the url structure for each board  to look like `https://<base_url>/boards/<committee_name>` and this will bring the user to the message board for that committee.

My routes.rb file looks like:

```
resources :committees, only: [:index] 
match '/boards/:name', to: 'committees#index(name)'
```

My index function of committees_controller.rb file looks like:

```
def index(name)  
   @posts = Committee.where(name: name)  
end
```

And then I'll use the `@posts` variable on the page to display all of the posts, but right now when I navigate to `https://<base_url>/boards/<committee_name>` I get an Unknown Action error, and it says `The action 'index(name)' could not be found for CommitteesController`.

Could someone guide me through what I have done wrong?

Once I get this working, how would I make a view that reflects this url structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your routes like this:

```
resources :committees, only: [:index]
match '/boards/:name', to: 'committees#show'
```

and the controller like this:

```
def index
   @committees = Committee.all
end

def show
   @committee = Committee.find_by_name!(params[:name])
end
```

You can't really pass arguments to controller actions the way you were trying to with `index(name)`. Instead, you use the `params` hash that Rails provides you. The `:name` part of the route declaration tells Rails to put whatever matches there into `params[:name]`.

You also should be using separate actions for the listing of committees and displaying single committees. Going by Rails conventions, these should be the `index` and `show` actions, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When routing, you only specify the method name, not the arguments:

```
match '/boards/:name', to: 'committees#show'
```

Generally you will declare something with `resources` or `match` but not both. To stay REST-ful, this should be the `show` method. Index is a `collection` method, usually not taking any sort of record identifier.

Arguments always come in via the `params` structure:

```
def show
  @posts = Committee.where(name: params[:name])
end
```

Controller methods that are exposed via routes do not take arguments. You may construct `private` methods that do take arguments for other purposes.